# Wrong window height on android when the HTML website is load

Tags: javascript, android, css, html, mobile

I am trying to write a mobile html5 website in which there's a Div that takes the whole size of the mobile device window. 
I've created a DIV with height 100% and put it inside the body, which also has height 100%, and the HTML tag has height 100%. 
For some reasons, when the page loads in android it takes only half of the window size, and when I query the window for its height it says that it's 229px instead of the 450px that it actually is. 
When I rotate the phone, and rotate it back, the window height becomes 450px. 
Why does it happen? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: What does your viewport meta tag look like?

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

Answer (score 1):

Use viewport :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: That's not what I asked. I know about viewport meta tag, and setting height=device-height doesn't help. The content height is actually correct, but android thinks that the window size is smaller than it is.

Comment: I think we need to see some HTML/CSS at this point if the meta tag advice isn't sticking.

Answer (score 1):

Posted the same solution to:
[Android browser's screen.width, screen.height & window.innerWidth & window.innerHeight are unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610743/android-browsers-screen-width-screen-height-window-innerwidth-window-inner/12724847#12724847)

The only constant among `window.innerHeight`, `window.outerheight`, etc was `screen.height`.

This code gave me the outerheight:

```
screen.height / window.devicePixelRatio - window.screenTop
```

Also, in order to support older versions of android, place your code in a `setTimeout`

I hope this is helpful =)

Comment: Have you tried debugging my suggestions to find out what exactly doesn't work? My answer is simply a suggested workaround that worked for me in the scenario laid out above and that time.