# How to get the viewport size in real device pixels?

Tags: javascript, mobile, responsive-design, viewport

There are `screen.width` and `screen.height` properties, that contain the screen width and height in real device pixels. However, they do not account for parts of the screen being taken by things not from the webpage, such as phone's status bar and browser's address bar / tab name with a button to expand the list of tabs. Is there any way at all to find out how much screen real estate does the browser actually allocates to the viewport?

Comment: you could set your body and html width and height to 100% and then use $(body).width() and $(body).height() if you are using jquery

Comment: related question, might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610743/android-browsers-screen-width-screen-height-window-innerwidth-window-inner

Answer (score 3):

`window.innerWidth` will provide you the width of the viewport.

`window.innerHeight` will provide you the height of the viewport.