# clientWidth,screen.width,android Chrome and viewport

Tags: javascript

I have 3 sub questions. I ran the following javascripts on my android phone(720*1280) with android Chrome. I ran it when the page start to load and within windown.onload.But i got strange results as below.

1. How come the body.clientwidth is larger than screen.width(I got the same results no matter if viewport meta is added or not)?
2. Why it returns 360*640 on android Chrome while it returns correct resolution on the other browser like UC? How can i get the correct resolution with android chrome?
3. I always got the same results on all browsers even when i set a viewport meta with device-width=320px; How come the viewport doesn't take effect?
4. document.body.clientHeight returns different value when execute it in window.onload which is larger. Why is that?

```
//execute with Android UC browser when page starts to load
document.writeln(window.screen.width);
document.writeln("<br />");
document.writeln(window.screen.height);
document.writeln("<br />");
document.writeln(document.body.clientWidth);
document.writeln("<br />");
document.writeln(document.body.clientHeight);

720
1280
964
114

//execute with Android UC browser in window.onload
document.writeln(window.screen.width);
document.writeln("<br />");
document.writeln(window.screen.height);
document.writeln("<br />");
document.writeln(document.body.clientWidth);
document.writeln("<br />");
document.writeln(document.body.clientHeight);

720
1280
964
266

//execute in Android Chrome when page starts to load
document.writeln(window.screen.width);
document.writeln("<br />");
document.writeln(window.screen.height);
document.writeln("<br />");
document.writeln(document.body.clientWidth);
document.writeln("<br />");
document.writeln(document.body.clientHeight);
360
640
360
640
32
964
132

//execute in Android Chrome window.onload
document.writeln(window.screen.width);
document.writeln("<br />");
document.writeln(window.screen.height);
document.writeln("<br />");
document.writeln(document.body.clientWidth);
document.writeln("<br />");
document.writeln(document.body.clientHeight);
360
640
360
640
32
964
308
```

Comment: I think this question (these questions?) is too broad. One part of the possible solution might be found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610743/android-browsers-screen-width-screen-height-window-innerwidth-window-inner

Comment: A quick aside: consider using `console.log()` and your browser's development tools instead of `document.write()`