# CSS - unable to fill entire screen on android after scrolling

Tags: css, css-position

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
        #header {position:fixed; height:100px; top:0px; left:0px; right:0px; background:black; color:white;}
        #overlay {position:fixed;  bottom:100px; top:100px; left:0px; right:0px; overflow:auto; background:gray;}
        #footer {position:fixed; height:100px; bottom:0px; left:0px; right:0px; background:black; color:white;}
        body {overflow:hidden;}
        </style>

</head>
        <body>
                <div id="header">header</div>
                <div id="overlay"><?php for($c=0; $c<100; $c++) echo '<p>overlay</p>'; ?></div>
                <div id="footer">footer</div>
                <?php for($c=0; $c<100; $c++) echo '<p>background</p>'; ?>
        </body>
</html>
```

Basically when you load this for the first time, you should see a gray area and black footer and header.  You can scroll the page to either the top end or bottom end, and you will always see ONLY the gray area and black footer.  The white background beneath these areas will never be exposed.  This works great in desktop browsers.

I have a problem with this code on android native browser.  When the page first loads, things work as expected.  But when you scroll to the bottom, the browser address bar hides itself, and then the white background shows up as a gap between the gray area and the black footer.  **How do I prevent this white background from showing up?**

Comment: do you have a CSS reset selectors? 
did you tried it on other browsers than Android's Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a common issue with Android browsers which sounds rather similar. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387028/wrong-window-height-on-android-when-the-html-website-is-load) and see if it helps.